# A basic java task that I just cant figure out

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I just cant figure out how to create a highscore function. I know that I have to have 2 values and compare them with an if statement and save them in SharedPreferences. Sharedpreferences I understand. What I cant understand is how to compare those 2 values?

In my program I have an int called score. It increases like score++ every time I answer a question correctly and at the end the answered question number is displayed. Lets say I play again and now get a larger number. How to compare them if their with the same name score? Do I need to assign the score to some new variable? how? I feel so dumb and emberresed right now..

CODE:
My score is stored here:

```
public static int scores = 0;
```

This is how I add +1 everytime:

```
   if (type.get(count[0])) {    
scores++; // Add +1 to the score; ...
```

I save my score here:

```
  protected void score() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
         if(scores > highscore) {

        highscore = scores;


        prefsEditor.clear();
        prefsEditor.putInt("score", scores);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
```

And show it in onther activity like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            int userScore = prefs.getInt("score", 0);

        mResult.setText("" + userScore);
```

Comment: you need persistence for storing a number or just one time is good ?

Comment: kindly consider adding the code of what you tried so far so that we can tell you what you missing

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I just need to show the highest score everytime I open my app. I don't care about other scores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you save the score in `SharedPreferences` every time you get a high-score and then when starting the app display that score:

```
// when starting the app
public static int userScore = 0;
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
userScore = prefs.getInt("score", 0);
mResult.setText("" + userScore);

public static int scores = 0;
   if (type.get(count[0])) {    
       scores++; 
    }
   if(scores > userScore)
   {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putInt("score", scores);
        prefsEditor.commit();
   }
```

Comment: What if I am displaying the score in a different activity? I cant compare scores to userScore then..

Comment: no you can, it's a public static var, just call `YourOtherActivity.userScore` instead of `userScore`

Comment: Woah I didn't even knew that was possible. That will help me a lot in the future. Your code worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a simple check (if you are only looking for the highest score, not other scores). Do an IF statement.

I dont know what you have called your high score but something like:

```
if (score > highscore){

highscore = score;

}
```

It should be quite simple, no? Then save this in configuration and have it pop up every time...

Comment: I have tried implementing your code but it doesn't work. Can you look at my updated post?